How to select a dropdown value in selenium python that has input html tags
I am finding it bit difficult to select a value from a dropdown using selenium python. This dropdown has the below html.
<input aria-invalid="true" autocomplete="off" id="asset-instrument-sub-type" 
type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd 
MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused css-mnn31" aria-autocomplete="list" 
aria-expanded="false" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" value="" 
aria-describedby="asset-instrument-sub-type-helper-text">

Once I click the dropdown there are 3 values in it (Equity, Fund, Others)
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="asset-instrument-sub-type" 
type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd 
MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused css-mnn31" aria-autocomplete="list" 
aria-expanded="false" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" 
value="Equity">

In my python script, I have this Xpath defined. First to select the DD and then to select the value "Equity" from it.
instrument_type_dd_xpath = "//input[@id='asset-instrument-sub-type' and @type='text']"
instrument_type_dd_for_equity = "//*[@id='asset-instrument-sub-type'] and 
@value='Equity'"

element=WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(by_locator))
element.click()

But when the script runs, the dropdown is expanded, but its not selecting the "Equity" value from it. Since there is no "select" or "li" tags, I am not sure how to select values from these type of dropdowns.
Any help is much appreciated.

while the selections are shown on the page, right-click on them and choose, "Inspect". Copy/paste the relevant markup into your question.  Also include a more complete version of the code you've tried.  (as is, "by_locator" isn't shown...)
